[&_.recharts-tooltip-cursor]:fill-zinc-200 what's the meaning?
I came across this piece of code. I've never seen this syntax before when writing Tailwind CSS. I'm not sure if it's a JSX feature or a Tailwind CSS feature. Does anyone know what this code means? Are there any relevant links you can provide?
<BarChart className="[&_.recharts-tooltip-cursor]:fill-zinc-200">

Does anyone know what this code means? Are there any relevant links you can provide?

what you have there is called an arbitrary variant. Arbitrary variants are just format strings that represent the css selector, wrapped in square brackets. They are used to modify or apply styles to elements that have specific class names.
In the code you provided, it is used to apply fill-zinc-200 to all elements with the class .recharts-tooltip-cursor within the element where you’ve added the class.
The & symbol refers to the parent selector, which in this case is the current element (BarChart). The _ (underscore) is a convention to indicate that a class is a variant or modifier of another class.
In summary, the <BarChart> element is assigned the class recharts-tooltip-cursor, and the fill property of its SVG elements will be set to the color defined by the zinc-200 color in the Tailwind CSS color palette.
Here are useful links you can consult to learn more about custom styles to TailwindCSS

Using arbitrary values
Using Arbitrary variants

Hope this helps. Cheers!
